# I try to use the GGR but it returns "connection refused" using selenoid in local

Tags: selenoid

I have installed selenoid, selenoid-ui, ggr and ggr-ui

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
8628fa3cc58e        aerokube/ggr-ui:latest-release   "/usr/bin/ggr-ui -..."   1 second ago        Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp   ggr-ui
f4e9c2ccc5c3        aerokube/ggr:latest-release      "/usr/bin/ggr -lis..."   16 seconds ago      Up 16 seconds                                ggr
beb1453e5c5d        aerokube/selenoid:1.6.1          "/usr/bin/selenoid..."   6 days ago          Up 6 days           0.0.0.0:4445->4444/tcp   selenoid
64dfb02d75fe        aerokube/selenoid-ui:v1.5.6      "/selenoid-ui --se..."   9 days ago          Up 9 days           0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   selenoid-ui
197dcabfb251        selenoid/video-recorder          "/entrypoint.sh"         2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks                                   nervous_albattani
1fc7e1423c86        selenoid/video-recorder          "/entrypoint.sh"         2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks                                   peaceful_wright
9e28f9224493        selenoid/video-recorder          "/entrypoint.sh"         2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks                                   frosty_saha
6b52e02770ef        selenoid/video-recorder          "/entrypoint.sh"         2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks                                   gallant_ramanujan`

If I use selenoid directly works successfully, but if  I use ggr, returns a error in the log  like that:

`2018/05/31 18:28:42 [INIT] [Loading quota files from /etc/grid-router/quota]
2018/05/31 18:28:42 [INIT] [Listen on :8888]
2018/05/31 18:29:05 [STATUS] [Failed to fetch status: Get http://localhost:4445/status: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4445: connect: connection refused] [172.16.0.173]`

Answer (score 3):

You are launching `Ggr` and `Ggr UI` in different way. For Ggr so far as I can see you are adding `--net host` flag. That means Ggr is using host machine network adapter and because of that specifying `localhost:4445` in quota file should work. In the case of Ggr UI you are only forwarding its port 8888 to host machine port 8888 thus using bridged network. Ggr UI container's `localhost` differs from host machine localhost and you get connection refused.

As a possible solution you can either add `--net host` to Ggr UI or use IP address or host name of the hosts machine in XML quota files. For example on Mac there's a DNS alias `docker.for.mac.localhost` allowing to access host machine inside containers.